Gradle Clean Stuck at 0% After Upgrading to Gradle 8.10 in React Native Project
i have updated API version to 35 and the gradlew version in my gradlew-wrapper.properties to:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10-all.zip

now i am trying to clean the gradlew after completing the installation of gradle-8.10 it stuck in evaluating it at 0 .
PS C:\QuickBiteApp\android> ./gradlew clean
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
<-------------> 0% INITIALIZING [12m 17s]
> Evaluating settings

I have tried to download another version but getting the same issue here also...

I am facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Yes, i have created a new project and moved my all screens and other component's there
